# Prevent sublime text from extracting keywords in comments for completion

Tags: sublimetext

How can I prevent sublime text from extracting keywords in comments?

e.g. I have the following javascript source file

```
// some keyword
```

I do not want to have either `some` or `keyword` to be in the completion list.

Thought it would be a common question but couldn't find anything on it.

Comment: I really don't think it's possible, unfortunately, unless you disable Sublime's completion, use a separate completion engine, and it has the option to not feed itself from comments. Search the issues [here](https://github.com/SublimeText/Issues/issues/), then [file a new one](https://github.com/SublimeText/Issues/issues/new) if you can't find a dupe.

Comment: @MattDMo Thanks for the suggestion. Filed an issue there, but I'm not expecting JPS to look at it.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Sublime Code Intel -  https://github.com/SublimeCodeIntel/SublimeCodeIntel - you can get read suggestions for the correct methods and variables rather that just words that are used in your code.

If you are on ST3 it's a little hard to get up and running, but it's totally doable.

I found these instructions to work https://johnblackbourn.com/sublimecodeintel-st3

Comment: There's the option `sublime_auto_complete` but for some reason that disables completion of variables as well.